# Set CPU register values while debugging a managed application in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, debugging, cpu-registers

I am debugging a .NET application in Visual Studio 2010 RC using disassembly view. The code is optimized and JIT-ed. At a particular point, I need to change the ZR CPU flag so that the JNE instruction would take a different path. For some strange reason, the registers window in Visual Studio is read-only and does not let me change register values, nor can I use "set next instruction" command to force the jumping myself. Any ideas?

P.S.: Are there alternatives, like a command for the "command window"? I doubt I could do it from the "Immediate window" since I don't think .NET allows register access.

Comment: If you don't mind using WinDbg instead of VS you can do all this and more.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're debugging .NET through disassembly?

Comment: Trying to track an issue in my code, debugging through mscorlib, so need it to behave differently than it is suppose to.

Comment: Isn't it a pain to set up WinDbg to work with managed code?

Comment: WinDbg is not the easiest tool to use, but with the sos.dll extension it is actually very useful for managed code. Check Tess' blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/default.aspx

Comment: Are you debugging attached as native, managed, or mixed?

Comment: i know i used to use registers from VC by doing an immediate window call using the register name; not sure that will help in this case... (e.g. i know you could do *(eax) = <some value>, but i'm not sure if you could set the register directly, nor if the flags register is accessible via name.)

Answer (score 1):

i was able to debug and just in the "Immediate Window" do:

`EFL = (some value)`

and it seemed to work.